# XO selection for 44.1kHz audio

Tags: audio, crystal, i2s, spdif

I'm implementing a [WM8804](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/WM8804_v4.5.pdf) S/PDIF transmitter in a project I'm working on. The datasheet states that clocks from 10MHz - 27MHz are supported.

What crystal oscillator frequency should I look for in order to support 44.1kHz I2S output given a an input of 44.1kHz S/PDIF?

Edit:

It looks like 12MHz would work fine, given the info below:

[image]

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

12 MHz is the default and only one that works in hardware mode so the PLL settings do not need to be altered.